# Text not being displayed on the first slide of a jQuery image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider

I'm building a site that's using a jQuery image slider.

In IE7 the paragraph text of the first slide doesn't appear until just before the script starts to change slides. It then appears fine on all subsequent slides. This makes me think that for some reason the image slider is hiding this text, but I'm really struggling to work out why?

Here's a link to the site: https://mariaridge.myshopify.com/

If anyone has any thoughts or ideas they will be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

These problems are quiet common under IE7.

What part of the text does disappear? Everything? Title? Paragraph?

Try positionning you text and/or container with css, for example with these css properties :

```
zoom: 1;
min-height: 0;
position: relative;
```